# Error in the second use of realloc(): Invalid next Size

Tags: c, memory, realloc

I am implementing a kind of dynamic map which will grow slowly depending on the actions we would perform in it. Basically, it's about representing the path to take after a series of direction taken (up, down, right, left). Therefore, I am thinking of a double table to which I will eventually add rows and columns with `realloc()` method. By testing my displacement function for a given type of movement, I have a good result for the first time I call the function (and therefore no problem reallocating my memory). But on the second call, everything is bad and I still can not understand the cause of the non-functioning of the `realloc`.

It throws this error:

> realloc(): invalid next size

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char **tab;
    int x;
    int y;
    int ligne;
    int colonne;
} Path;


Path* InitPath(){
    int i, j;

    Path *myPath = (Path*) malloc(sizeof(Path));

    myPath->ligne = 3;
    myPath->colonne = 3;

    myPath->tab = malloc(sizeof(char)* myPath->ligne );
    for(i=0; i< myPath->ligne; i++)
        myPath->tab[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*myPath->colonne);

    for(i=0; i<myPath->ligne; i++)
        for(j=0; j<myPath->colonne; j++)
            if( i ==1 && j ==1)
                myPath->tab[i][j] = 'S';
            else
                myPath->tab[i][j] = '#';

       myPath->x = 1;
       myPath->y = 1;

       return myPath;
}

    
void addWay(Path* myPath, char* theWay){
    int i, j;
    char copie;

    if( strcmp("up",theWay)==0 ){

        if( 0 == myPath->y -1 ){
            //on ajoute une ligne
            myPath->ligne+=1;

            // printf("%ld\n", myPath->ligne * sizeof(char));
            //on alloue de la memoire pour cette ligne
            myPath->tab = realloc(myPath->tab, myPath->ligne * sizeof(char));
            myPath->tab[myPath->ligne-1] = malloc(sizeof(char)*myPath->colonne);

            //on la rempli
            for(i = 0; i<myPath->colonne; i++){
                if(i == 0 || i== myPath->colonne -1 )
                    myPath->tab[myPath->ligne-1][i] = '#';
                else if (i==myPath->x)
                    myPath->tab[myPath->ligne -1][i] = '*';
                else
                    myPath->tab[myPath->ligne -1][i] = ' ';
            }

            //on inverse
            for(i=myPath->ligne -1; i > myPath->y; i-- ){
                for(j=0; j<myPath->colonne; j++){
                    copie = myPath->tab[i][j];
                    myPath->tab[i][j] = myPath->tab[i-1][j];
                    myPath->tab[i-1][j] = copie;
                }
            }
        } else {
            myPath->y -= 1;
            myPath->tab[myPath->x][myPath->y] = '*';
        }        

    }
    // else if(strcmp("down", theWay)){

    // }else if(strcmp("left", theWay)){

    // }else if(strcmp("right", theWay)){

    // }

    // return myPath;
}

void showPath(Path* myPath){
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i< myPath->ligne; i++){
        for(j=0; j< myPath->colonne; j++)
            printf("%c", myPath->tab[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void destroyPath(Path* myPath){
    free(myPath->tab);
    free(myPath);
}

int main(){

    Path* new = InitPath();

    showPath(new);

    addWay(new, "up"); //Well

    printf("**********************\n");

    addWay(new, "up"); // Error

    showPath(new);

    // printf("%d %d %d %d", new->x, new->y, new->ligne, new->colonne);

    destroyPath(new);
}
```

Comment: sorry for the closing}

Comment: `myPath->tab = malloc(sizeof(char)* myPath->ligne );` should be `myPath->tab = malloc(sizeof(char *) * myPath->ligne );` and similar for the `realloc`. That is `sizeof(char)` should be `sizeof(char *)`